# Laravel Nova not loading any resources, blade error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

Nova was working for me before. I started working on the front-end, and when coming back to Nova it suddenly doesn't work anymore. I can log in, but then it shows the loading animation for all resources and it's not loading data.

I get this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: longpath/location.blade.php)
```

In `location.blade.php`

```
@extends('app')

@section('title')
    {{ $location->title }}
@endsection

@section('content')

@endsection
```

The weird thing is that on the front-end, location.blade.php loads perfectly fine, as I pass the `$location` variable in the `LocationController`. No errors and nothing in the error log. In `LocationController`:

```
$location = Location::
  where('id', $this->location_id)
  ->first();

return view('location', [
  'location' => $location
]);
```

So it shows the error, and this error is in the logs as well. If I comment out `{{ $location->title }}`, it doesn't show the error anymore, but it's still not loading any data, and nothing shows up in the error log. So I have no clue why it's not loading any data. It's also a mystery to me why a (front-end) Blade template would generate an error in Nova, while it works perfectly fine on the front-end.

**Update:**

If I comment out this specific route in routes/web, Nova works again. Not sure why this route impacts Nova?

```
Route::get('/{location_id}/{location_title}', 'LocationController@viewLocation');
```

If I add the route back in, in my console I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: What is `$this->location_id`? Is there a matching record in the database with the same id? Essentially, with your current query, `$location` is `null`, so trying to call `$location->title` is throwing that error. Consider adding some logic to handle a redirect if not found, like `if(!$location){ return redirect("/home"); }`, etc.

Comment: `$this->location_id` is defined in the `LocationController` by `public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->location_id = $request->route('location_id');
    }` As indicated this works fine on the front-end. I've just updated the answer, the culprit seems to be the route but not sure why that impacts Nova.

Comment: Ah, so yes. If you see the answer below, it points out the problem. If you were to navigate to something like `myapp/api/test`, your route would be trying to query for a location with an id of `api`, which it's not going to find.

Comment: I edited in another possible solution after you accepted. Take a peek - `->where('location_id', '[0-9]+')` may do the trick on your route, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is problematic because:

```
Route::get('/{location_id}/{location_title}', 'LocationController@viewLocation');
```

is going to catch **any** `/foo/bar` URL.

If you do `php artisan route:list | grep nova` you'll see all of Nova's routes, and you'll find a bunch in this format:

- `/nova-api/metrics`
- `/nova-api/cards`
- `/nova-api/search`
- `/nova-api/{resource}`

etc. etc. etc.

(In other words, a bunch of Nova's routes are being sent to your `LocationController` instead of the right Nova controllers.)

You may be able to fix this by taking the `Nova::routes` call out of the `app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php` file and putting it in your routes files directly, but the cleaner solution is likely to adjust your route to be something like `/locations/{location_id}/{location_title}` that's not going to conflict. Wildcarded top-level routes tend to cause issues like this.

You may also be able to do this:

```
Route::get('/{location_id}/{location_title}', 'LocationController@viewLocation')
   ->where('location_id', '[0-9]+');
```

This will make your route only activate for numeric IDs, which means it won't interfere with the non-numeric `nova-api` routes.